# Autogenerated number with the use of date and time c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having trouble on how am i going to autogenerate a number with the use of date and time. For example, i need to generate this kind of number, 16-9685 with, 16 = year and 9685 be randomized and will be shown in a textbox. i tried this one but unfortunately, this doesn't work. thanks for helping

```
var random = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Year);
int randomNumber = random.Next(-1000, -1);
TextBoxSESID.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
```

Comment: Assuming `16` is the year "2016" and year is **not** random, wouldn't you want to concatenate these two values?  Also, the `ctor` of `Random` is a seed value- usually you'd want to use `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` here.

Comment: I know you're specifically asking for a number, but without knowing what the core task is I have to ask if a GUID wouldn't meet your needs

Comment: @Hambone - How you you expect a `Guid` to work here?

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi, the answer below is the right answer. But it's just a thought, is there any possible way that if, example the number that is picked is 8765, will never be picked again ? thanks.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I realize it didn't answer his question directly...  I was just trying to dig deeper.  The whole random number based on date/time thing was starting to sound like he's looking for a UID and perhaps the datatype didn't matter

Comment: @voter93481741 - I've added a solution for making sure you don't a get a repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Keep this _r as a member, not local
Random _r = new Random();
...

// Gen a random number
int rand = _r.Next(1, 10000);

// Get the "2016-" prefix
string yearPrefix = DateTime.Now.Year + "-";

// Remove the first 2 digits of the year prefix, now it is "16-"
yearPrefix = yearPrefix.Substring(2);

// Put the year prefix together with the random number into the textbox
TextBoxSESID.Text = yearPrefix + rand;
```

Comment: is there any possible chance, that if you pick the number, it will not going to be pick again ? example is that, if the number 8685 is picked and save, it will never be pick again.

Comment: Use GUID if you're looking for universal-uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that this is a nice clean way to produce the string you require:

```
TextBoxSESID.Text = $"{DateTime.Now.Year % 100}-{_r.Next(1, 10000)}";
```

If you're not using C# 6 then this will work too:

```
TextBoxSESID.Text = String.Format("{0}-{1}", DateTime.Now.Year % 100, _r.Next(1, 10000));
```

You still need have this as a field:

```
private Random _r = new Random();
```

If you want to ensure that no two names are repeated (assuming that you never use more than 9,999 names) then do this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "16.txt",
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 9999)
        .Select(n => $"{DateTime.Now.Year % 100}-{n}")
        .OrderBy(x => _r.Next()));
```

Now you have a file that has all the possible numbers in a random order.

To get a new number do this:

```
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("16.txt");
    var first = lines.First();
    File.WriteAllLines("16.txt", lines.Skip(1));
```

It will take the top line and re-save the file without it.

Just make sure you create files for each year as it comes along.